# Longitude from different vantage points

Tags: positional-astronomy

Given, the mean longitude L of the Earth-Moon barycenter, as seen from the Sun's center.
From this, is the mean longitude of the Sun L+180°, or is it 360°-L, as seen from the Earth-Moon barycenter?

Tried ChatGPT but this does not answer my question.

Comment: It is 180+L.  E.g. if EMB is at 0, then the Sun is at 180.  If the EMB is at 90, the Sun is at 270.

Comment: Indeed, this must be the right solution.